# How to get current script filename or path in python when instantiate a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
# utils.py
class Foo:
    def __init__():
        print(__file__)

# mod.py
from utils import Foo

foo = Foo()
# This prints /absoulte/utils.py
# the expected output is /absoulte/mod.py
```

Is it possible to make the imported class `Foo` initialization with current file info instead of where it defined without passing the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module. I don't know your particular case use. But if you keep everything super simple this approach can make the job done:

```
import inspect
from pathlib import Path

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        # Get a list of every frames (almost a callstack) 
        outerframes = inspect.getouterframes(frame)
        # Go one level up
        outerframe = outerframes[1]
        # Get the file name as a Path object to take the name easily
        outer_filepath = Path(outerframe.filename)
        # Print the file name
        print(outer_filepath.stem)
```

Keep in mind that this is a very fragile solution. For instance it might not work as expected if you inherit your class. If you define `class Faa(Foo)` in a file called `Faa.py`, whenever you instantiate `Faa` the function `Foo.__init__` will print `Faa` (for `Faa.py`), and not the file where you are making the instantiation.

For more complex cases you might want to get hacky and play around with [`outerframe.function`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.FrameInfo.function) to look for a function not called `__init__` or even [`outerframe.context[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.FrameInfo.code_context) to look for a explicit call to the class.